# Any statistics on the likelihood of, consumption frequencies and dosages required for serotonin syndrome to occur with LSD?

Tags: statistics, psychopharmacology, drugs, serotonin, psychedelics

This may be too obscure of a question to have sufficient, if any, statistics on it. If that's the case, any relevant information is appreciated.

From what I've gathered, very high doses and/or very frequent use of LSD (or any other psychedelic for that matter) is necessary for [serotonin syndrome](https://www.webmd.com/depression/guide/serotonin-syndrome-causes-symptoms-treatments) to occur in typical, healthy people.

Are there any statistics on how often serotonin syndrome occurs with LSD consumers, and what dosage level and consumption frequency is associated with that likelihood?

I know some drug combinations greatly increase the likelihood, but I'm most interested in the likelihood with just LSD.